# Copying text from Word to textarea

Tags: php, forms, character-encoding, ms-word

A well-known problem: When copying text fro MS Word into a textarea, the text's characters get converted to strange characters when saving it to database.

I was wondering how I should solve this?

1. Character encoding of the HTML document that holds the form
2. A before save method to sanitize the data
3. Sanitization after retrieving the data (before displaying)
4. A database configuration (character encoding for table)

I would prefer if 1. worked, but any other solution will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution:

1. Character encoding of the HTML document that holds the form

This does *normally* <sup>1</sup> work. If it does not work, your applpication is broken or the browser is broken or the clipboard is broken or MSWord is broken.

In any case, you can not fix MSWord *nor* the Clipboard, *nor* the browser server-side.

Instead ensure that the encoding the website is using can deal with the characters from the clipboard, and honor the encoding requests into your application have when you process input data.

<sup>1</sup> Please see [Handling character encodings in HTML and CSS](http://www.w3.org/International/tutorials/tutorial-char-enc/) how it works.

Comment: I'd have voted this up if it weren't for the fact the most common cause, by far, is bad programming - failing to match the charset on the html to the charset being processed by PHP, and failure to map the charset in PHP to the charset used by the database.

Comment: @symcbean: Well: *"honor the encoding requests into your application have when you process input data"* ;) Anyway, I know what you mean, it's just that this question was asking about pasting from MSWord specifically. Maybe it's worth you add an answer where you make the points 2-4 more clear.