# Copy & Paste Non-Breaking Hyphen from MS-Word to a HTML-Textarea

Tags: javascript, html, ms-word

When I copy and paste text from a MS-Word (Office 16) document into a `<textarea>`  of my website in Chrome, the non-breaking hyphens are replaced with space.

Is there any way I can catch and change the content before the paste event or a setting in Word?

Usually if an unknown character is pasted over from Word a `` symbol appears (which can be replaced via regexp) but not in this case.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Copying text from Word to textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7739839/copying-text-from-word-to-textarea)

Comment: No. Sadly not. Usually if an unknown character is pasted over from Word a  symbol appears (which can be replaced via regexp) but not in this case.

Comment: this all are no ascii character. you have handle this to avoid.

Comment: Either write an EditCopy() sub that asks you every time whether you want a regular copy or a "special" one which replaces the non-breaking hyphens with something you can process with a regexp, or  create a. new Sub that does that every time and associate it with a different keystroke.